# Web services and hibernate - how would you combine these two?

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, jaxb

I would like to use hibernate for persisting objects through web services and am thinking of using hyperjaxb3 with Apache CXF. Do you have any other suggestion for this purpose?

Edit: To clarify my question a little bit... I am using eclipse and wsgen, wsimport ant tasks to generate my service and client classes respectively. I am using annotations to configure entities which are persisted by hibernate. With this setting I encountered a few simple issues which I was able to fix by googling around. Then I encountered a problem with cyclic references which I fixed with afterUnmarshal (described [here](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html) ). Afterwards I encountered a problem of entity with two parents (two bidirectional relationships) which I tried to solve with @XmlID and @XmlIDREF in the way described [here](http://syrupsucker.blogspot.com/2008/05/jpa-identity-intergerlong-or-string.html) but didn't make it in the end. And at that time I began to wonder if I am doing something wrong and should use different tools/technologies (should I maybe switch to maven, or introduce spring, etc.) so I investigated a little bit and found out about hyperjaxb3 and am wondering if that could be the solution to my problems? :)

Edit 2: In short, which way you use, prefer or just do in most cases involving these two?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what it is you are curious about using these two? Exposing web services which internally use Hibernate for data access is a very common practice. What is the exact question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) has extensions for handling JPA entities, for more information see:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the [Spring MVC Tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/), which you'd be able to integrate with Hibernate quite easily.